# Is there a way to find an item in a tuple without using a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I have a tuple of `Control` values and I want to find the one with a matching name. Right now I use this:

```
listView
for control in controls:
    if control.name == "ListView":
        listView = control
```

Can I do it simpler than this? Perhaps something like:

```
listView = controls.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "ListView")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
listView = next(c for c in controls if c.name == "ListView")
```

Note that this will raise a `StopIteration` if no matching item exists, so you will need to put this in a try/except and replace it with a default if you get a `StopIteration`.

Alternatively you can add your default value to the iterable so the `next` call always succeeds.

```
from itertools import chain
listView = next(chain((c for c in controls if c.name == "ListView"), [default])
```

If you are using Python 2.5 or lower change the call from `next(iterable)` to `iterable.next()`.

Answer (score 2):

Out of sheer curiosity, I integrated my own answer with your original code and F.J.'s solutions to make a comparative performance test.

It seems that your solution is the fastest of them all. My solution check all possible elements of the controls tuple, so it will be slower as the size of the tuple increases.

Here is the code:

```
from timeit import Timer as T
from itertools import chain, dropwhile

class control(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def johan_venge(tuple_):
    for el in tuple_:
        if el.name == 'foobar':
            return el
    return None

def mac(tuple_):
    return filter(lambda x : x.name == 'foobar', tuple_)[0]

def mac2(tuple_):
    return list(dropwhile(lambda x : x.name != 'foobar', tuple_))[0]

def fj(tuple_):
    return next(c for c in tuple_ if c.name == 'foobar')

def fj2(tuple_):
    return next(chain((c for c in tuple_ if c.name == 'foobar')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    REPS = 10000
    controls = (control('hello'), control('world'), control('foobar'))
    print T(lambda : johan_venge(controls)).repeat(number = REPS)
    print T(lambda : mac(controls)).repeat(number = REPS)
    print T(lambda : mac2(controls)).repeat(number = REPS)
    print T(lambda : fj(controls)).repeat(number = REPS)
    print T(lambda : fj2(controls)).repeat(number = REPS)
```

and here is the output on my system:

```
[0.005961179733276367, 0.005975961685180664, 0.005918025970458984]
[0.013427019119262695, 0.013586044311523438, 0.013450145721435547]
[0.024325847625732422, 0.0254058837890625, 0.02396702766418457]
[0.014491081237792969, 0.01442408561706543, 0.01484990119934082]
[0.01691603660583496, 0.016616106033325195, 0.016437053680419922]
```

HTH! :)

Comment: Thanks for this test. Btw I am not sure how to interpret the output though :O You have results side by side for the same method but different results for each, line by line?

Comment: @JoanVenge - Take a look at the documentation for [`timeit.Timer.repeat`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat). Basically it's three runs of 10.000 iteration each for each solution.

Comment: Thanks mac, now it does make sense. This is probably basic but I noticed you used `'`, but other answers use `"`, any difference for this?

Comment: I agree, it does look less cluttered :O

Answer (score 1):

```
listView = filter(lambda c: c.name=="ListView", controls)[0]
```

Throws *IndexError* if no such control exists.

A bit esoteric, but without requiring try/except:

```
listView = (lambda x: x[0] if x else None)(filter(lambda c: c.name=="ListView", controls))
```

Comment: We basically posted the same solution simultaneously! Check my answer if you are interested to see how fast it is compared to the others! :)

Comment: Can this be modified like FJ's answer so it doesn't throw an exception without using try/catch? Just curious.

Comment: @JoanVenge - You can if you break it in two lines: first line `filt = filter(...` only. Second line: `return filt[0] if len(filtered) > 0 else None`.